# Reduce Object items based on Array using underscore

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

Having this:

```
array = []
array.push(111,2122,333,9)

obj.user = {
    '111'  : {},
    '2122' : {},
    '333'  : {},
    '44'   : {}
}
```

How can I get a new object containing only the elements that exist in the array?

In the case above, it would return:

```
{
    '111': {},
    '2122': {},
    '111': {}
}
```

I have tried this:

```
var newObj = _.keys(_.pick(obj.user, function(value, key) {
  if ( _.indexOf(array, parseInt(key)) != -1 ) {
    return obj.user[key]
  }
}));
```

Which works fine when testing on jsfiddle, but it crashes my app with `process out of memory`. The objects/arrays are not that large, maybe 20-30 items, but that piece of code gets executed quite a lot of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`_.pick`](https://underscorejs.org/#pick):

```
const result = _.pick(obj.user, array);
```

Live Example:

```js
const array = [];
array.push(111,2122,333,9)

const obj = {
  user: {
    '111'  : {},
    '2122' : {},
    '333'  : {},
    '44'   : {}
  }
};

const result = _.pick(obj.user, array);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Recommend avoiding "Try this:" followed by code. Say what you've used, and ideally when it's something like `_.pick`, link to it (see my edit).

Comment: Running with this code for 15 minutes and so far the app didn't crash. Thanks.